# Generata jsondata robotframework

Tags: robotframework

i got this response :

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "me",
        "sku": "one"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "you",
        "sku": "two"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "us",
        "sku": "three"
    }
]
```

and i want to create new jsondata like this in robotframework as bodydata in another request:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "me",
            "id": 1,
        },
        {
            "name": "you",
            "id": 2,
        }
    ],
}
```

how can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried converting the json to a python dictionary, changing the dictionary, and then converting it back?

Comment: never do that, and still doest know how to doing that. can you give me some hint.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your implementation, but this works for your example and should give you clue how to solve your problem in general. I have used robotframework-jsonlibrary and ended up with this code. I have put your example response in original.json file and then loaded. You can omit this line, because you already have json loaded in some variable.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  JSONLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
test
    ${json}=  Load JSON From File  original.json
    ${json}=  Delete Object From Json    ${json}    $.[-1]
    ${json}=  Delete Object From Json    ${json}    $..sku
    ${new_json}=  Convert String to JSON  { "users": [] }
    ${json}=  Update Value To Json  ${new_json}  $.users  ${json}
    log to console  ${json}
```

JsonLibrary:
https://robotframework-thailand.github.io/robotframework-jsonlibrary/JSONLibrary.html#Load%20JSON%20From%20File